# A nullpointer exception arise when I try to call a method in my drawingview class from my activity

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to include a simple drawing activity in my app.  The activity allows me to draw but I get an error when I try to change the color. The error arise when I call the DrawingView method from the Activity. The debugger doesn't allow me inside the method.

**The following error shows up in the logcat:**

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.reitron.putmaster.ActDrawingView.setColoring(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I have an activity, a DrawingView class and a layout.

**Here is the relevant code of the activity:**

in the onCreate:

```
drawView = (ActDrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
        LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
        currPaint = (ImageButton)paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));

    public void paintClicked(View view){
        //use chosen color
        if(view!=currPaint){
            //update color
            ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton)view;
            String color = view.getTag().toString();
            drawView.setColoring(color);
           // drawView.setColor(color);
            imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
            currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
            currPaint=(ImageButton)view;
        }
    }
```

**The code from the DrawingView class:**

```
public class ActDrawingView extends View {


    private Path drawPath; //drawing path
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint; //drawing and canvas paint
    private int paintColor = 0xFF000000;   //initial color
    private Canvas drawCanvas;    //canvas
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap; //canvas bitmap

    public ActDrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
        setUpDrawing();
    }

    private void setUpDrawing() {
        // get drawing area for interaction
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        //view given size
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //draw view
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //detect user touch
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                drawPath.reset();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public void setColoring(String newColor){
        //set color
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }

}
```

**And here are snippets in the layout file**

```
<com.reitron.putmaster.ActDrawingView
    android:id="@+id/drawing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
            android:onClick="paintClicked"
            android:src="@drawable/paint"
            android:tag="#FFFF0000" />
```

Please can you help me find the error?

Tx!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke `.setColoring(color)` on an object that is probably missing or hasn't been initialized. In your case, I can see that drawView is the thing in question. You invoke it here:
`drawView = (ActDrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);`
, but I reckon that if you put a breakpoint at the invokation point I just mentioned, `findViewById(R.id.drawing)`, would return null(a.k.a it hasn't found the view. Make sure this drawing is properly initialized (maybe put it in the Layout folder (I think it should be as it's a view (I could be wrong)))) and try again. Nevertheless, the point of error is right there..

Comment: Nikolai, you are correct that the findByView returns null.  However, the .xml is located in the layout folder and the interesting thing is that I can draw on the DrawingView that is called by the .xml. I cannot call the method though.

Comment: Have you done this in your Activity's OnCreate(): 'setContentView(R.layout.drawing);' ?

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_drawing);

Comment: I see... What I think is the problem, from my really short experience with Android, is that you cannot invoke the View with that specific id, because it is not in the layout that is currently on the screen. What I mean is that you are calling the view 'R.id.drawing', but it has to be in the current layout (a.k.a 'R.layout.act_drawing') in order for the method 'findViewById(R.id.drawing)' to find it. You cannot change something that has not been executed yet. (that is why it returns null)

Comment: Nikolai, thanks for all the kind help.  In frustration I deleted all the files and retyped all the code. Now it works! I do not know why...